Error in installing Angular Material while implement template
I've created a new project in Angular my Node version v20.13.1 and Angular version v18.0.1. I downloaded a free template from CodedThemes and added all the template files to my project, following their documentation. However, when I attempted to add Angular Material to it by running the script ng add @angular/material, an error occurred.
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/material@17.3.10.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/material@17.3.10 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @angular/cdk@17.3.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=16.0.0" from ngx-scrollbar@13.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/ngx-scrollbar
npm ERR!       ngx-scrollbar@"^13.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^17.3.6" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@angular/material)
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"18.0.0" from @angular/forms@18.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^18.0.0-next.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @angular/material@17.3.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"17.3.10" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@17.3.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:

✖ Packages installation failed, see above.

Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-eslint/schematics@17.3.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cli@18.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/cli@"~18.0.0-next.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cli@">= 17.0.0 < 18.0.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@17.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR!   dev @angular-eslint/schematics@"17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/cli@17.3.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cli@">= 17.0.0 < 18.0.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@17.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR!     dev @angular-eslint/schematics@"17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\DR99\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-28T08_17_08_293Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DR99\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-28T08_17_08_293Z-debug-0.log
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.```


The error is due to @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0 not being compatible with the newly released Angular 18.
Here are some ways to resolve this problem:

Downgrade Angular Version
If there is no compatible version of @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, consider downgrading Angular to a version that is compatible with @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0 (e.g., Angular 17).

Use --force or --legacy-peer-deps
If you understand the risks and are willing to potentially deal with inconsistencies or broken dependencies, you can force the installation:
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

However, I tried forcing the installation and running the program, and I didn't notice any obvious errors. If this is a project for learning purposes, you can temporarily choose this solution.


Wait for @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap to support Angular 18
I checked the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap repository and found that there is already an issue related to this, and a PR has been submitted to support Angular 18. I believe a new version will be released soon.
Related link:
Issues · ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap (github.com)
Dependency Error after upgrate to angular 18 · Issue #4706 · ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap (github.com)
build: update angular 18 by bastienmoulia · Pull Request #4704 · ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap (github.com)



actually i new in angular .how i know which version is compatible

Since Angular 18 has just been released, the package dependencies may not have been updated promptly. You can try specifying the version of @angular/material:
ng add @angular/material@18
I've tried it and it works. Hope this helps you.

no same issue occures

can i send you my project

https://codedthemes.com/item/berry-angular-free-admin-template/ this is the template that i used

i delete node_module and package_json after delete when i run npm install they again show same error

Upon closely reviewing your code, I found that the error is due to @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0 not being compatible with the newly released Angular 18. I have updated my response accordingly.

my project is succesfully run without any error but when i add angular material and then again  error comes

Please execute the following commands one by one.
npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force -> npm uninstall ng-apexcharts --force  -> ng add @angular/material  -> npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force -> npm install ng-apexcharts --force

after runnning npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force -> npm uninstall ng-apexcharts --force scripts when i run ng add @angular/material again error comes

It works fine on my device. Maybe your project dependencies differ from berry-free-angular-admin-template? Can you provide the new error message?

Got it. You added ESLint. Following the same approach, uninstall '@angular-eslint/schematics' first, then add '@angular/material', and reinstall  '@angular-eslint/schematics'. If errors (npm ERR! While resolving: xxxxx) still occur after adding '@angular/material', proceed with the same steps .

Alternatively, you can directly execute 'npm install @angular/material --force' to install '@angular/material', and then configure it manually.

again error occurred while uninstall @angular-eslint/schematics

Please add the --force parameter after the command.
